# Передача двумерного массива из php в js

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

В файле main.php есть код:

```
<?

if(isset($_POST['id'])){
    $db->Query("SELECT * FROM db_cases WHERE status = '1' && id = '".intval($_POST['id'])."' ");
    $res = $db->FetchArray();

    $json = $res['list_weapons'];
    $weapons = json_decode(base64_decode($json), true);
    $count_items_for_js = count($weapons);
    include("../ajax/roulette.php");    
}

?>
```

В файле `roulette.php` мне нужно задать в массив `img` значение массива `$weapons`

```html
var f = 1; var a = new Array(); // Это ID пушки в кейсе.
var img = new Array("-");
    <? $i = 1?>
    for(f; f <= <?=$count_items_for_js;?>; f++) {
        <? $i++; ?>
        a.push(f);
        img.push(<?=$weapons[$i]['img']?>);

    }
```

Для справки: цикл выполняется нужное количество раз. Только вот к `$i` единица не добавляется. И в массив `img` забивается первый элемент массива `$weapons` ***n*** раз.

Я осознаю что написал говнокоД, и он не работает. Что в двойне печально.

Прошу помощи !

Comment: а `f` чему равен? =)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский var f = 1;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

За самокритику + (=

А теперь по делу... Серверная часть не знает о наличии клиентской как и наоборот, т.е.  исполняются отдельно. У вас серверная часть отдаёт только 1 элемент массива, который и крутится в последствии на клиенте нужное количество раз.

Вам необходимо организовать цикл на стороне сервера (php).

```
var imgArray = [
<? for($i=1; $i<$count_items_for_js;$i++): ?>
    '<?=$weapons[$i]['img']?>'<? if(($i+1)!=$count_items_for_js): ?>,<? endif; ?>
<? endfor; ?>
];
```

Comment: Написал так: var f = 1;
 
  var a = new Array(); // Это ID пушки в кейсе.
  var img = new Array("-");
  
  <?php for($i=1; $i <= $count_items_for_js; $i++): ?> 
  a.push($i); img.push('<?=$weapons[$i]['img']; ?>'); 
  <?php endfor; ?>
  
  alert(a); - не работает

Comment: `a.push($i);` ни чего не смущает?

Comment: a.push(<?=$i;?>);

Answer (score 1):

```
    for(f; f <= <?=$count_items_for_js;?>; f++) {
    <? $i++; ?>
```

Ты путаешь где и что у тебя выполняется. Цикл у тебя JS - он выполняется в браузере пользователя *после* того как браузер целиком получил созданную с помощью php страницу. А во второй строке у тебя идет увеличение php переменной, которое происходит на стороне сервера. И на стороне сервера никакого цикла у тебя вообще нет. Тебе надо делать весь цикл в php и формировать для JS готовый массив

Ну если совсем криво то так:

```
var a = new Array(); // Это ID пушки в кейсе.
var img = new Array("-");
<?
for($i=1; $i <= $count_items_for_js; $i++):
    print "a.push($i);";
    print "img.push('"+$weapons[$i]['img']+"');";
endfor;
?>
```

P.S. правда совершенно не понимаю, зачем вам нужен массив `var a` на стороне клиента, у меня очень стойкое подозрение, что он там не нужен

Comment: Я уже понял. Но как ? Не могу придумать, потому и прошу помощи...

Comment: Ща попробую написать ...

Comment: Буду признателен !

Comment: @Mike  а об альтернативном синтаксисе `for` не, не слышали?))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Да, слышал как то. мне привычнее сишная нотация.

Comment: @Mike рекомендую все же добавить: `<?php for($i=1; $i <= $count_items_for_js; $i++): ?>
    a.push($i);
    img.push('<?= $weapons[$i]['img']; ?>');  
<?php endfor; ?>`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Ну тут разницы только в `:` вместо `{` и `endfor` вместо `}`  Каков глубокий смысл использовать такой синтаксис

Comment: @Mike чтоб человек знал. Да и вообще это уже практически стандарт использования кода во фронтенде. Там только альтернативный синтаксис и используют. А иначе человек будет засирать код изначально неправильно по вашей же наводке)) особенно когда код большой будет и много вложенностей циклов и условий

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Очень жаль, что такая дурацкая (с моей точки зрения) нотация стала стандартом. Я на php обычно только чужое правлю, а держать в голове разные нотации, когда за день переключаешься между несколькими языками, довольно тяжело. И так то и дело $i начинаешь в C лепить :) Постараюсь для Стака последовать Вашей рекомендации

Answer (score 1):

Сначала выполняется весь php; HTML и JS отдаётся в браузер клиента, и только тогда выполняется JS.

Если правильно понял, требуется заполнить JS массив `img` полями "img" из `$weapons`. Можно в `roulette.php` примерно так:

```
var a = []   // Это ID пушки в кейсе.
    ,img = ["-"]
    ,weapons = <?php echo json_encode($weapons) ?>
    ,i = 0
;

for( ; i<weapons.length; i++) {
    a.push(i);
    img.push(weapons[i].img);
}
```